# Cordova: unable to read file content from sdcard

Tags: android, cordova, android-storage

I'm trying to read the content of a file located in `/storage/emulated/0/...` using [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/). I'm able to get the related `FileEntry` and read some properties like name, type or size but when I use a `FileReader` to read the content it fails with `FileError {code: 1}`

[FileError - API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError) states that error code 1 is `NOT_FOUND_ERR` but I'm sure the file exists. As I said, I'm able to retrieve it's size (I've checked that the value is correct!).

I use the following code to test:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
  "cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/ticket/fake.pdf",
  function(fileEntry) {
    console.log("ENTRY URL " + fileEntry.toURL());
    console.log("IS FILE: " + fileEntry.isFile);

    fileEntry.file(function(file){
      console.log("FILE: " + file.name);
      console.log("SIZE: " + file.size);
      console.log("TYPE: " + file.type);

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log("READER END");
        console.log(this.result);
      };
      reader.onerror = function(er) {
        console.log("READER ERROR");
        console.log(er);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }, console.error);
  },
  console.error
);
```

the output is:

```
ENTRY URL file:///storage/emulated/0/ticket/fake.pdf
IS FILE: true
FILE: fake.pdf
SIZE: 32471
TYPE: application/pdf
READER ERROR
ProgressEvent {type: "error", bubbles: false, cancelBubble: false, cancelable: false, lengthComputable: false, …}
READER END
```

where: `ProgressEvent.target` is `FileReader` and `ProgressEvent.target._error` is `FileError {code: 1}`

I've also tried with other paths or files:

- `file:///storage/emulated/0/ticket/fake.pdf`
- `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190412_110205.jpg`

**AndroidManifest.xml** has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The answers to other similar questions that I have found propose as a solution what I am already doing.

**UPDATE:**

It seems to be a permissions problem. If I do

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/ticket/fake.pdf", okFunction, errorHandler);
```

it doesn't triggers the permission request to the user. But it does with:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("cdvfile://localhost/sdcard/ticket/fake.pdf", function(f) {
  f.filesystem.root.getFile(f.fullPath, {}, okFunction, errorHandler)
}, errorHandler);
```

Once the user accepts the permission, all methods works fine.

Now my question is why if I use the `FileEntry` from `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to read the content it doesn't request the permission but it does for the `FileEntry` from `filesystem.root.getFile`.